# HTTP port scan in .NET

Tags: .net, http, port

Say I know the IP address of a machine/device which is using a non-standard HTTP port. Is it possible in .NET to scan the ports of said device - not just to find its open ports - but to find the specific port which is used for HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could connect to each port (find the ones that are open), and if it is open you can send a HTTP request to it, if it responds you know that port is open for HTTP.